# React Hook API, should I need set deps for SetStateAction?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a question to use react hook api

```
const Example: FC = (props) => {
    const [str, setStr] = useState('example');
    const onClickCb = useCallback(() => {
        setStr(str + '_');
    }, [str, setStr]); // should I need watch setStr?
    return <button onClick={onClickCb}>{str}</button>;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't need to add `setStr` as it will not change during the lifetime of the component. But there is also not much harm in adding it as it will not change.

From the [`useState` react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate):

> **Note**
>
> React guarantees that `setState` function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the `useEffect` or `useCallback` dependency list.

But you should definitely remove `str`. State should not be updated based on the current state as [react may batch multiple calls to `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). This could lead to updates happening in a short period of time getting lost. Instead use the callback version of `setState`:

```
const Example: FC = (props) => {
    const [str, setStr] = useState('example');
    const onClickCb = useCallback(() => setStr(current => `${current}_`)), []);
    return <button onClick={onClickCb}>{str}</button>;
};
```

Comment: In my opinion there is no need for using useCallback in this example at all. It adds more complexity for almost no benefits. But trixn's answer is correct if you really want to use hook.

Comment: @PavelKratochvil Then how do you prevent passing a new callback on every render of `FC` without `useCallback`?

Comment: why do you even need that in this case?

Comment: @PavelKratochvil Well this is obviously a made up example to illustrate the point. The question was about whether there is a need to pass the updater function of `useState` to the dependency list of `useCallback`. Here it is needed for the illustration purpose. In almost every other practical use case there will be a benefit. A rule of thumb: If you pass it as a handler use `useCallback`.

Comment: I said that your answer is correct when it comes to the question. :) Just pointed that in this example there is no neef for using it. Meybe the example isn't there just for ilustration but its real example, who knows. All i want to say is: do not overengineered it just because you can :)

Comment: @PavelKratochvil If I'm pedantic about that I could argue that even in this example there is a benefit from it. The props passed to `FC` could change (we do not know what is getting passed) which would lead to a re-render of the `<button>` component even if it does not consume the changed prop at all.  But to be fair, yeah in this example you could probably leave it away.

Comment: If we go to details, there will be no rerendering though, just actualizing react node and dom node callback. I just usually prefer straight forward solution over the most optimized one so i wanted to share that idea with person who was asking.